# Java Jackson Serialize JSON to HashTable

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am trying to serialize a list of JSON blobs and put certain keys into a HashTable during the serialization. Here is an example of my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "sally",
        "id": 1,
        "eye_color": "green"
    },
    {
        "name": "jack",
        "id": 2,
        "eye_color": "blue"
    },
    {
        "name": "jane",
        "id": 3,
        "eye_color": "brown"
    }
]
```

What I am looking for specifically is a POJO (or set of POJOs) which can serialize the above JSON like so with Jackson assuming the above JSON is in a file called `above_json.json`:

```
MyPOJO pojo = objectMapper.readValue(new File("above_json.json"), MyPOJO.class);
```

I want the result of the serialization to give me a `HashTable` (or an `Object` which encapsulates the `HashTable`) where the `HashTable` `key` is the value of `name` and the `Hashtable` `value` is the value of the corresponding `id` above.

Assuming we serialized the above JSON in this fashion, I would want to access the `HashTable` like so:

`myTable.get("jane")`

result: 3

`myTable.get("jack")`

result: 2

`myTable.get("Jill")`

result: `null`

I know how to serialize basic JSON with Jackson. I have an example like below:

JSON Input:

```
"Parameter":{
    "Name":"Parameter-Name",
    "Value":"Parameter-Value"
}
```

POJO to serialize above simple JSON:

```
public class Parameter {
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("Value")
    public String value; 
}
```

But obviously this type of setup does not put the results into a `HashTable`. I need a POJO like what I have in this example which will serialize JSON directly into a `HashTable`

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, you probably don't want to use a `HashTable`, as it's considered to be an obsolete type (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)).

Either use a `HashMap` or if you want thread safety, a `ConcurrentHashMap` or a thread-unsafe `Map` backed by `Collections.synchronized[...]` and referenced to within `synchronized` statements.

**Secondly**, you can use a [TypeReference](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) to de-serialize as your desired type.

**Finally**, your JSON's syntax is incorrect: it starts with a square bracket (`[`) and ends with a curly bracket (`}`), which is technically unparseable.

Assuming you want an array of `Map`s here (e.g. `HashMap<String, String>[]`), here is some suitable code, provided you replace the last curly bracket with a square one:

```
// the map array
Map<String, String>[] map = null;
map = om.readValue(yourFile, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>[]>() {});
// prints the de-serialized contents
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map));
```

**Edit**

Since you have now edited your JSON to remove the first square bracket and replace it with a curly bracket, **no** you can't parse as a `Map` as is.

**Edit 2**

Since you have now **re-edited** your JSON to feature square brackets once again instead of curly brackets in the wrapping object, you can once again de-serialize as a `Map[]`. Until the next edit, I guess...

Comment: I don't think that this will work, as it will create array of hashmaps.
Only one hashmap/hashtable is required.

Comment: Yes, it will de-serialize an array of maps. OP's JSON is unparseable as is, so this is the assumption.

Comment: Thanks for this response, I appreciate it. All I am looking for is a single HashMap with keys and values directly from the JSON. Also, thanks for catching my error in the JSON. I fixed it now :)

Comment: @Ryan your JSON does not feature keys and values. It features a wrapper containing objects that are themselves de-serializable as maps.

Comment: What if I were to have square brackets on the ends? Would it be possible to serialize the whole thing into a single map with keys and values as I described?

Comment: @Ryan because a wrapper object made of child maps is not a map. It just isn't the same data structure. A map is made of keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible.

You serialize this json into a list of pojos, and have a utility function to generate the hashtable in the way you desire from the list of pojos.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realize that I can easily serialize a list of POJOs and then slap them into a HashMap as desired. This is kind of slow though. I was hoping I could save some time by putting it directly into the HashMap rather than first serializing into other POJOs and then having to iterate through each one.

Comment: I think that is not possible looking at the structure of your json.

if it would have been of the form: 

{"name1":id, "name2":id, ...... }

Then it would have been possible to serialize it directly into a hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO for holding the properties you are interested in.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
private static class MyPOJO {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Deserialize the contents of the file into `List<MyPOJO>`

```
 List<MyPOJO> myPOJO = mapper.readValue(new File(".."), new TypeReference<List<MyPOJO>>(){});
```

Stream the contents of the map to construct a map whose key is the `name` and value is the `id`.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = myPOJO.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyPOJO::getName, MyPOJO::getId));
```

Comment: This looks like it could work for me! I will give it a shot and mark this as the answer if it works for me. Thank you.